# Good val accuracy but bad prediction/bad confusion matric

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, confusion-matrix

I got a issue when I try to plot the confusion matrix, it's appear that the model didn't learn anything even if I get "good" val and test acc.

```
def create_chevaux_rgb2(directory) :
  
  # Create training set
  train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
      directory,
      labels='inferred',
      label_mode='int',
      class_names=("Confortable","Inconfortable"),
      color_mode='rgb', #rgb ou grayscale
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      image_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
      shuffle=True,
      validation_split=0.3,  # Use 70% for trainset
      subset="training",     # Specify training subset
      seed=123,
      interpolation="mitchellcubic")

  # Create validation set
  test_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
      directory,
      labels='inferred',
      label_mode='int',
      class_names=("Confortable","Inconfortable"),
      color_mode='rgb',
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      image_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
      shuffle=True,
      validation_split=0.3, 
      subset="validation", 
      seed=123,
      interpolation="mitchellcubic")
  
  #plot_image(train_dataset)
  
  test_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_dataset)
  validation_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_batches // 2)
  test_dataset = test_dataset.skip(test_batches // 2)

  # split dataset : train 70%, val 15%, test 15%
  print('Number of train batches: %d' % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_dataset))
  print('Number of validation batches: %d' % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_dataset))
  print('Number of test batches: %d' % tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_dataset))

  AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

  train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  validation_dataset = validation_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  test_dataset = test_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

  return train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset
```

Data information :
2 classes, 491 pictures / 492 pictures
Return :
Found 979 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 686 files for training.
Found 979 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 293 files for validation.
Number of train batches: 43
Number of validation batches: 9
Number of test batches: 10

```
def fine_tuning_test(train_dataset, validation_dataset, test_dataset, CHANEL=3) : 

  preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input
  
  data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
  layers.RandomContrast(0.3),
  layers.RandomBrightness([-0.1, 0.4])
  ])
  
  IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE) + (3,)
  base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                include_top=False,
                                                weights='imagenet')

  image_batch, label_batch = next(iter(train_dataset))
  feature_batch = base_model(image_batch)
  base_model.trainable = False
  global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
  feature_batch_average = global_average_layer(feature_batch)
  prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

  inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
  x = data_augmentation(inputs)
  x = preprocess_input(x)
  x = base_model(x, training=False)
  x = global_average_layer(x)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
  outputs = prediction_layer(x)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

  base_learning_rate = 0.00001
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Lion(learning_rate=base_learning_rate),
                loss="binary_crossentropy",
                metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                         tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1,
                                                  average='macro',
                                                  threshold=0.5)])
  
  initial_epochs = 50
  history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=initial_epochs, callbacks=CALLBACKS,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset)

  list_epochs = [history.epoch[-1]]
  history_fine = []

  # training n°2
  base_model.trainable = True
  fine_tune_at = 15
  for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at] :
    layer.trainable = False
  model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Lion(learning_rate=base_learning_rate/10),
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                         tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1,
                                                  average='macro',
                                                  threshold=0.5)])

  fine_tune_epochs = 50
  total_epochs =  initial_epochs + fine_tune_epochs
  history_fine.append(model.fit(train_dataset, callbacks=CALLBACKS,
                          epochs=total_epochs,
                          initial_epoch=history.epoch[-1]+1,
                          validation_data=validation_dataset))

  list_epochs.append(history_fine[-1].epoch[-1])

  # training n°3
  base_model.trainable = True
  fine_tune_at = 11
  for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at] :
    layer.trainable = False
  model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Lion(learning_rate=base_learning_rate/100),
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                         tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                         tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1,
                                                  average='macro',
                                                  threshold=0.5)])

  fine_tune_epochs = 50
  total_epochs =  initial_epochs + fine_tune_epochs*2
  history_fine.append(model.fit(train_dataset, callbacks=CALLBACKS,
                          epochs=total_epochs,
                          initial_epoch=history_fine[-1].epoch[-1]+1,
                          validation_data=validation_dataset))
  
  list_epochs.append(history_fine[-1].epoch[-1])
  loss, accuracy, Precision, Recall, F1Score = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
  plot_curves_test(history, history_fine, list_epochs)

  return model
```

Training result :

```
Training : 
Epoch 60/60
43/43 [==============================] - 16s 336ms/step - loss: 0.3667 - accuracy: 0.8440 - precision_11: 0.8347 - recall_11: 0.8613 - f1_score: 0.8478 - val_loss: 0.6926 - val_accuracy: 0.6875 - val_precision_11: 0.6667 - val_recall_11: 0.6957 - val_f1_score: 0.6809
Evaluation :
10/10 [==============================] - 5s 42ms/step - loss: 0.7576 - accuracy: 0.6376 - precision_11: 0.6049 - recall_11: 0.6901 - f1_score: 0.6447
```

[acc/loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU0Fd.png)
Confusion matrix result :

```
def get_actual_predicted_labels(model, dataset):
  actual = [labels for _, labels in dataset.unbatch()]
  predicted = (model.predict(dataset) > 0.5).astype("int32")

  actual = tf.stack(actual, axis=0)
  predicted = tf.concat(predicted, axis=0)
  #predicted = tf.argmax(predicted, axis=1)

  return actual, predicted

def plot_confusion_matrix(actual, predicted, labels):
  cm = tf.math.confusion_matrix(actual, predicted)
  ax = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g')
  sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6, 6)})
  sns.set(font_scale=1.4)
  ax.set_title('Confusion matrix of emotion recognition')
  ax.set_xlabel('Predicted emotion')
  ax.set_ylabel('Actual emotion')
  plt.xticks(rotation=0)
  plt.yticks(rotation=90)
  ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)
  ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)

label_names = ["Confortable","Inconfortable"]
```

Confusion matrix with trainset :

```
actual, predicted = get_actual_predicted_labels(model_1, **train_ds**)
plot_confusion_matrix(actual, predicted, label_names)
```

[Confusion matrix with trainset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiIhl.png)

Confusion matrix with testset :

```
actual, predicted = get_actual_predicted_labels(model_1, **test_ds**)
plot_confusion_matrix(actual, predicted, label_names)
```

[Confusion matrix with testset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FkCW.png)

How even with the train I got this ?

I expected good confusion matrix.

Comment: Have you also tried to plot a ROC/PR curve? Apart from this your model is overfitting a bit (~15% less accuracy on validation)

Comment: the issue come from the function predict so every other metrics will be impacted even ROC/PR

Answer (score 1):

I cannot verify this assumption because your code is incomplete and not executable, but I suspect it is because you are fetching labels and images separately.

```py
  actual = [labels for _, labels in dataset.unbatch()]
  predicted = (model.predict(dataset) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

Since your dataset has `shuffle=True`, doesn't this cause the labels and images to be loaded in a different order?

Comment: I don't think so.